# Changing values of duplicates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of stock prices. There is possibility of duplicates and hence while performing merge functions data goes haywire. What i want is whenever there are duplicates in any column, i want to increment it with small amounts.

Eg.Table

```
|Date| High| low|
|:--|:---:|---:|
|1-12-2020| 515|505|
|2-12-2020| 525|515|
|3-12-2020| 515| 510|
|4-12-2020|530 |505|
```

In above table we had instance of high and low repeating. Hence will increment the duplicates by say very minsicule amount 0.0025

**Desired output**

```
|Date| High| low|
|:--|:---:|---:|
|1-12-2020| 515|505|
|2-12-2020| 525|515|
|3-12-2020| 515.0025| 510|
|4-12-2020|530 |505.0025|
```

What function should i use to solve this problem
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`df.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
In [1421]: df.loc[df.duplicated('High'), 'High'] = df.loc[df.duplicated('High'), 'High'] + 0.0025

In [1423]: df.loc[df.duplicated('low'), 'low'] = df.loc[df.duplicated('low'), 'low'] + 0.0025

In [1424]: df
Out[1424]: 
        Date      High       low
0  1-12-2020  515.0000  505.0000
1  2-12-2020  525.0000  515.0000
2  3-12-2020  515.0025  510.0000
3  4-12-2020  530.0000  505.0025
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is this. Your dataframe is ddf

```
        Date  High  low
0  1-12-2020   515  505
1  2-12-2020   525  515
2  3-12-2020   515  510
3  4-12-2020   530  505
```

and doing this

```
mask = ddf['High'].duplicated(keep=False)
ddf.loc[mask, 'High'] += ddf.groupby('High').cumcount().add(1)
```

returns

```
        Date   High  low
0  1-12-2020  516.0  505
1  2-12-2020  525.0  515
2  3-12-2020  517.0  510
3  4-12-2020  530.0  505
```